# Node Js JSON file table name isn't what I want

Tags: node.js

```
function doWrite(value1, value2, value3, athor)
{
    fsLibrary.exists('./users/' + athor + '.json', function(exists) {
        if (exists) {
            console.log("File exists already, adding to existing one");
            let jsonDataExists = JSON.parse(fsLibrary.readFileSync('./users/' + athor + '.json'));
            const nameData = value1;
            jsonDataExists.nameData = [];
            jsonDataExists.nameData.push({name: value1, level: value2, exp: value3});
            var writeData = JSON.stringify(jsonDataExists, null, 2);
            fsLibrary.writeFile("./users/" + athor + ".json", writeData, (error) => {
                if (error) throw err;
            });
            console.log("Wrote to " + athor + ".json\n" + writeData);
        }
        else {
            console.log("File doesn't exist, creating one");
            var jsonDataNew = {};
            var obj = {
                name: value1,
                level: value2,
                exp: value3
            };
            jsonDataNew.table = [];
            jsonDataNew.table.push(obj);
            var writeData = JSON.stringify(jsonDataNew, null, 2);
            fsLibrary.writeFile("./users/" + athor + ".json", writeData, (error) => {
                if (error) throw err;
            });
        }
    });
}
```

This code results in a table name of "nameData" instead of what I set nameData to. Any help?
I've tried putting jsonDataExists.{nameData} and (nameData), and the result of those is just crashing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you should use [] in order to set the attribute name using a variable, like this:

```
fsLibrary.exists('./users/' + athor + '.json', function(exists) {
      if (exists) {
          console.log("File exists already, adding to existing one");
          let jsonDataExists = JSON.parse(fsLibrary.readFileSync('./users/' + athor + '.json'));
          const nameData = value1;
          jsonDataExists[nameData] = [];
          jsonDataExists[nameData].push({name: value1, level: value2, exp: value3});
          ...
      }
      else {
          ...
      }
  });
```

In order to recreate what you described, I've simplified the code to this:

```
  let jsonDataExists = {};
  const nameData = "bla";
  jsonDataExists[nameData] = [];
  jsonDataExists[nameData].push({name: "value1", level: "value2", exp: "value3"});
  console.log(jsonDataExists);
```

and what is printed out is this:
{"bla":[{"name":"value1","level":"value2","exp":"value3"}]}

notice the syntax options for the property accessor in javascript object:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '['
C:\Users\BotHost\Desktop\Test Bot\bot.js:64
                        jsonDataExists.[nameData] = [];

Comment: is that the full line?  it should be 
jsonDataExists[nameData] = [];

Comment: I can only put in so much of the error due to SO's limitation. But yes that is the full line.

Comment: I've edited to show the code I used to check this, I think you left a dot before the [nameData], remove it :)

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. Thank you so much! I'm glad this was a simple fix. Removing the dot worked.

Comment: happy to help :) I added a link to a reference if you want to read more about property accessors :)